# What is the correct way to typedef [Symbol.iterator]?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code to paginate in Angular:

```
  get meetingsPage() {
    const start = this.pagination.pageSize * ( this.pagination.currentPage - 1)
    const end = this.pagination.pageSize * this.pagination.currentPage;
    const meetings = this.meetings;
    return {
        *[Symbol.iterator]() {
            for (let i = start; i < meetings.length && i < end; i++) {
                yield meetings[i];
            }
        }
    };
  }
```

It works, but the linter complaints with the following message:

> expected call-signature: '[Symbol.iterator]' to have a typedef
> (typedef)

meetings is an array of Meeting interface.

What can i do to make the linter happy?

UPDATE:

I end up with the following, and now the linter doesn't complaint:

```
  get meetingsPage(): Iterable<Meeting>} {
    const start = this.pagination.pageSize * ( this.pagination.currentPage - 1)
    const end = this.pagination.pageSize * this.pagination.currentPage;
    const meetings = this.meetings;
    return {
        *[Symbol.iterator](): Generator<Meeting, void> {
            for (let i = start; i < meetings.length && i < end; i++) {
                yield meetings[i];
            }
        }
    };
  }
```

Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: As a side not - in most cases typescript is smart enough to infer the type on its own and this this rule is not really helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your linter expect that your `*[Symbol.iterator]()`

will be typedef, with

`interface Generator<T,TReturn,TNext> extends Iterator`

like:

`*[Symbol.iterator](): Generator<Meeting, void> {`

Comment: Or more specifically `Generator<Meeting, void>`